# JavaScript game, Sprites

Tags: javascript, sprite

I'm trying to create a JavaScript game. The main player is an html image of a Pikachu. I'm trying to implement methods where the Pikachu image can jump, move left/right. What's the best way to implement this? Is there a way to implement physics methods on an image?

Comment: You can start with https://phaser.io/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to go with Sprites and Entities.